# External "Asset Library"

Tags: feature, external-content-type, image

Any idea if SharePoint has an extensibility point to add an external DAM store as a normal Asset source for images or other media files?

Answer (score 2):

OOTB SharePoint hasn't this feature, btw you could use the RBS Implementation: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649.aspx

or a solution from Avepoint or Metalogix

Comment: Definitely a good fit for RBS scenario. there are also some file integration products like what Bamboo offers, but it is not as seamless as RBS, and not specifically for Media.

Answer (score 0):

For Videos at least you could consider leveraging IIS Media Services. Microsoft has a few posts on leveraging both on site and Azure media services.  This doesn't require RBS, however the video source will not actually be SharePoint.

Do a search for:

"Delivering End-End Video Workflow Using Microsoft SharePoint,IIS Media Services,Microsoft Expression Encoder and Microsoft Silverlight"

or

"Steve Fox SharePoint IIS Media Video"